# elasticsearch get only parents documents from index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get all parent documents from an index.
there is any way to do this?

I have tried this:

```
"must": [
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": "join",
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "name": "post"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

and this:

```
"must": [
    {
      "has_child": {
        "type": "comment",
        "query": {},
        "min_children": 0
      }
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

every child documented in the index has _routing field.
if I want only parent documents they must haven't _routing field.
so I will add "must_not" to the query to make sure that the documents with _routing  field will not be returning.

solution:

```
"must_not": [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "_routing"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO :) It is always good to [explain the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) how it will help solving the problem :)